# Removing double quotes from beginning and end of String

Tags: php

What I'm trying to find out is which php function allows me to remove double quotes from the beginning and end of a text string if they exist

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function:

```
$str = '"Hello"';
echo trim($str, '"'); // Outputs Hello
```

Comment: So that will REMOVE quotes at the front and beginning of my text string?

Comment: @user1333299 Yes, it will remove double quotes from the beginning and end, even if there are more than one, so `""""x""y"` would become `x""y`

Comment: What would be the opposite of that though. Like for example if I want to add them to the beginning and end of a text string?

Comment: @user1333299 You can't undo it if you don't know how many quotes there were originally. You can add one quote to the begining and end thought like this: `$str = '"' . $str . '"';`

Answer (score 6):

[Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is your friend:

```
trim($string,'"');
```