# Input crash on read slashes

Tags: php, mysql, input, crash

I'm getting a problem with saving input to my DB.

I save my string to my DB as:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($my_string)
```

Then, I read and I place the string to the input using this:

```
stripslashes($my_string)
```

The point is, if I set double slashes into my string, the inputs crash like this:

```
<input maxlength = "150" type="text" name = "my_string12" value = "hello "this is" a test"  class="input-medium"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That should work. But I can't tell to my users to use single quotes instead double slashes...

Answer (score 0):

If the value as PHP variable then you have to trim it ..

Use the trim function:

```
$str = 'hello "this is" a test';
echo trim($str, '"'); // hello this is a test
```

answered by paul at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262951/removing-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

`<?php echo addslashes('hello "this is" a test'); // hello \"this is\" a test ?>`

an stripslashes to remove it

`<?php echo stripslashes('hello \"this is\" a test'); // hello "this is" a test ?>`

or just type it like this

`value = 'hello "this is" a test'` or `value = "hello 'this is' a test"`