# Evaluate a string as PHP code without using eval

Tags: php, eval

Seeing how eval should be avoided, how do you evaluate a string as PHP code **without using eval**? For example consider this code:

```
<?php

$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.'; 

$str = "\"$str\""; // Now I have a string with double quotes around it. 

// how to get the contents of $str evaluated without using eval()

?>
```

I can get the desired result by using eval like so - `eval("echo $str;");`, but eval is exactly what I am looking to avoid.

You might view this as a question of removing the double quotes. But it isn't about that. As @AmalMurali points out, what I am asking here is `how to get the contents of $str evaluated without using eval()`

Comment: Don't put double quotes around it then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262951/removing-double-quotes)

Comment: @MihaiIorga: How is this question a duplicate of that? This one asks how to get the contents of `$str` evaluated without using `eval()`.

Comment: @MihaiIorga I have edited my question to better reflect my exact query. I dont feel its a duplicate anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can layout your code like this:

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a ' . $string . ' with my ' . $name . ' in it.';
```

Or perhaps like this, using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) which is my personal favorite method of handling cases like this:

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = sprintf('This is a %s with my %s in it.', $string, $name);
```

There are different options based on personal style & preference.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want here is to use double quotes for $str so that variable replacement can take place.

See also the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding double quotes then removing them? For a simple string variable inclusion you just use double quotes like

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it."; 

echo $str;
```

Comment: I have edited my question to better reflect my needs.