# How to use str_pad using array_map in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I'm trying to use `str_pad` using `array_map` in PHP. But it seems like it is not working. A code-snippet:

```
$arr = ["", "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"];
$arr = array_map("str_pad", $arr, [4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT]);
var_dump($arr);
```

Result is:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "    "
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ab"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
}
```

I can't explain myself this behaviour .. that `$arr[0]` is filled, but just with whitespaces instead of zeroes and the other elements are like before.

How to adapt my code so that is returns something like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0000"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "000a"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "00ab"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "0abc"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
}
```

Comment: I have already answered a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286693/php-array-map-trim-parameters/41286762#41286762

Comment: The callback function is ran for each element in each array passed in the arguments. It will match `""` with `4` , `"a"` with `0` and `"ab"` with `STR_PAD_LEFT`. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go ([working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa2a7072add18dde918ef98f4db7ac2e6b70a5f5))

```
$arr = ["", "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"];
$arr = array_map(function ($item) {
       return str_pad($item, 4, "0", \STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    },
    $arr
);
var_dump($arr);
```

You can have a look in the manual for more details on how [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) works. Basically if you call it with multiple arrays, on the first call the first parameter of the function will the the first element of the first array and the second parameter will the be the first element of the second array and so on and so forth.